# using dataticket for more than one text box with same id

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using text box in more than on place in a same page. i have assign the `datepicker` for the `textbox` but the `textbox` is not showing the date in one of the `textbox`

Comment: Hiya man, May I recommend you to rethink and rephrase your question please, soon you will be asked for: what have you tried **or** show us some code **or** this aint research site, letting you know before hand <I won't down vote you though> B-) **One Answer** add a class to all your text boxes and then initialize the date picker on the class like this  `$('.class_name').datepicker()`

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want...

Comment: Elements on the page should NOT have the same ID - see the HTML 4.0 specification dating back to 1999 for more information.

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want....

Answer (score 0):

try this way

**html:**

```
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date_1" />
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date_2" />
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date_3" />
```

**script:**

```
    $('.datepicker').each(function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
```